# upload a xml file to the win server

Tags: android, file-upload

Xml file stored on the my Sdcard.

I want  to upload xml file to server.

I'm using the [Apache Commons Net 3.2 Library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/download_net.cgi).

I've used the following code:

```
    FTPClient con = new FTPClient();
    try
    {
        con.connect(InetAddress.getByName("ftp.domin.com"),21);

        if(con.login ("username","password")){
            con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            con.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/test.xml");
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
            con.storeFile("test.xml", in);
            in.close();

        }
        if(con.isConnected()){

            Log.i(TAG,"Connect to server");
        }else{

            Log.i(TAG,"No Connect to server");
        }
        con.logout();
        con.disconnect();    

    }
    catch (Exception e){    
        Log.e(TAG, e.getStackTrace().toString());
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

But it shows the following error:[error photo](http://s1.picofile.com/file/7719817418/U.png)

and I've used the following permission :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

The important thing here is that I can not run this section:

```
            if(con.isConnected()){

            Log.i(TAG,"Connect to server");
        }else{

            Log.i(TAG,"No Connect to server");
        }
```

Please help me !

thanks.

Comment: Do you have an error related to the file that is downloaded؟

Comment: I understand
I used to be a thread

Comment: Please change the host of your image: picofile.com doesn't support https.